# pdo exception "colunt not find driver in ..."

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

in mainpage.php file, I use this:

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=webfilter_schema';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password); //WORKS.
```

and its fine. But in another php file:

```
<?php

class HomeController {

public $pdoObject; // handle of the db connexion
private static $instance;

public function __construct()
{
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=webfilter_schema';
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $this->$pdoObject = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);// Error line..
}

public function createLocalObject(){
    $query ="INSERT INTO USERS SET NAME = ?, PASSWORD = ?,IPADDRESS=?,E_MAIL=?";
    $process = $this->pdoObject->prepare($query);
    $insertResult = $process->execute(array("asd","ferfr","23","sadsads@hotmail.com"));

    if($insertResult)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

?>
```

it throws an exception like

> Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\WP\Controller\HomeController.php5 on line 25

what is it happen ?

Comment: Forgot to end the dsn string?! And pgsql ? mysql?! choose one! Also change `$this->$pdoObject ` and remove the dollar sign from the property -> All in all: [Start from the bottom, before you fly](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Comment: @Rizier123 I forgot nothing.. just variable names diffirent

Comment: 1. Now you updated your question 2. You problem is that you have spaces in your dsn!

Comment: @Rizier123 I copied wrong but now its same.. still gives error

Comment: Are you using namespaces?

Comment: no but now error message changed. "Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\WP\Controller\HomeController.php5 on line 21"

Comment: Seeing `WP` ... are you using Wordpress? Plus, how are you using the `HomeController` class?

Comment: Please make sure you show us your **full** and **real** code also update your error message which you get and mark the line with a comment in the question

Comment: @Fred-ii- no, I just try to imitate .net MVC framework.

Comment: Again, how are you calling/using the `HomeController` class? I don't see `new HomeController();` anywhere.

Comment: it was in main.php file, when I debug it everything is fine till come that line which try to make PDO connection. But I figure out the problem it cases of language ı think when I try this:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just added language as parameter..

```
public function __construct() { 
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=webfilter_schema'; 
$username = 'root'; 
$password = ''; 
$options = array( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8', );
$this->pdoObjectp = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options); 
}
```

and it works.